# SugarCRM - Rest API - order_by and limit

Tags: api, rest, sugarcrm

I am trying to use REST API to retrieve last 10 modified records using 'get_relationship' method.

How hard I try , i could not able apply order by / limit or both.

My codes as below

```
$get_relationships_parameters = array(
     'session'=>Yii::app()->user->sid,
     'module_name' => 'Contacts',
     'module_id' => Yii::app()->user->id->value,
     'link_field_name' => 'project',
     'related_module_query' => ' name  like "'.$searchkey.'%"',
     'related_fields' => array(
        'id',
        'name',
        'date_modified',
     ),
     'related_module_link_name_to_fields_array' => array(
     ),
     'deleted'=> '0',
     'order_by' => 'date_modified desc',
     'offset' => 0,
     'limit' => 4,
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might see a similar example shown on my Blog [SugarCRM: How to get list of all documents related to an account](http://www.dontesta.it/blog/en/blog-2/crm/sugarcrm-ottenere-lelenco-i-documenti-relativi-account/?goback=.gde_65181_member_272166830#!)

It really does seem strange. I ran a test with a record limit equal to 5 and everything works fine. The account that I took as an example associated six documents. The sample code that I used on my repository is at this address [getRelateDocument.php](https://gist.github.com/amusarra/6436845), and to follow the output of the request. The test was performed on the Community Edition version 6.5.8.
[image]

```
(
[entry_list] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 1c7d4b6b-ca64-485f-7aed-52d8625001f0
                [module_name] => Documents
                [name_value_list] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => id
                                [value] => 1c7d4b6b-ca64-485f-7aed-52d8625001f0
                            )

                        [name] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => name
                                [value] => TrackerReport.zip
                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 5037454c-5ca9-2f2f-6843-52d862448506
                [module_name] => Documents
                [name_value_list] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => id
                                [value] => 5037454c-5ca9-2f2f-6843-52d862448506
                            )

                        [name] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => name
                                [value] => wpi_hook_v4.zip
                            )

                    )

            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 50790693-a318-cc8a-592f-52d863da7ebc
                [module_name] => Documents
                [name_value_list] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => id
                                [value] => 50790693-a318-cc8a-592f-52d863da7ebc
                            )

                        [name] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => name
                                [value] => Schedulers.zip
                            )

                    )

            )

        [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 8b4c0450-1922-498f-4601-52272fa6e494
                [module_name] => Documents
                [name_value_list] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => id
                                [value] => 8b4c0450-1922-498f-4601-52272fa6e494
                            )

                        [name] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => name
                                [value] => WebProxyService_A.png
                            )

                    )

            )

        [4] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 930e4fed-61f6-c24e-b8fc-52d863def56b
                [module_name] => Documents
                [name_value_list] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => id
                                [value] => 930e4fed-61f6-c24e-b8fc-52d863def56b
                            )

                        [name] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => name
                                [value] => Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.3.0.pdf
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[relationship_list] => Array
    (
    )
```

)

Comment: Hi Antonio,Thanks. I used exactly as it is in the blog. But no luck. It not limiting number of records. I always get more than limit specified. Any other suggestion.

Comment: Hi,Try to see the review of the response.

Comment: Your example works as it is with my data. I will  verify what is issue with my methods . Thank you so much.

Comment: HI Antonio. Found the issue. I am using REST Version V4. Thanks for your code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. After changing rest call url to v4_1, it start working.

Do i have something missing in order_by as well?. I can not able to sort by date_modified. Any clue?

Regards
Marthala

Comment: seems to be it is a bug.http://www.sugarcrm.com/support/bugs.html?task=search#issue_59526